add SAN's to cluster config with rancher
I've created a k8s cluster with rancher. 3 controlplanes, 3 workers.
The plan was to install kube-vip on the cluster for a virtual IP with IP let's say 10.10.10.10.
So I added 10.10.10.10 to the "TLS Alternate Names" in Networking section on the create cluster screen. So after the cluster was created and download the kubeconfig. And change the server section into server: https://10.10.10.10:6443
kubectl outputs this message still:
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Is it possible to add more SAN's to kubeconfig certificate with rancher?
